# How to disable alert when push notification is received and app is close in swift?

Tags: swift, push-notification, onesignal

When my app is opened and it receives push notification alert is disable But when app close show alert

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                appId: "appid",
                                handleNotificationReceived:{ (notification) in

     let payload: OSNotificationPayload? = notification?.payload              
     let fullMessage: String? = payload?.body
     print("Recived no" + fullMessage!)
     print("Received Notification - \(notification?.payload.notificationID) - \(notification?.payload.title)")

    },
                                handleNotificationAction: nil, 
                                settings: [
          kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : false,
          kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts : false
    ]
)
```